# Unable to deploy through capistrano after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano

I recently upgraded my development machine to Ubuntu 15.04 (was 14.04LTS) and ran into a problem when trying to deploy changes to my server. The interesting bit is, that I can ssh into my server without any issues (hence, the key file is setup correct), but when I try to deploy via capistrano I get `permission denied`.

So this works:

```
ssh admin@1.2.3.4
```

and this raises `permission denied` when contacting the server.

```
cap deploy
```

I also tried deploying from a different machine, which works fine. So that tells me that the error is somewhere within the new OS. Has anybody experienced something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the RSA identity is not added to the authentication agent.

To add the identity, just run the command `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`